"k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime".Object (missing method DeepCopyObject)
I am new to go and Kubernetes. Facing this error in making the custom K8 schduler plugin. I did everything using this link Kube-Scheduler-Plugin, everything is done but when I am running

./hack/update-codegen.sh

This file not creating the DeepCopyObject since when I run the make command it gives this error
$ make
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags '-w' -o bin/controller cmd/controller/controller.go
GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags '-X k8s.io/component-base/version.gitVersion=v0.0.20240430 -w' -o bin/kube-scheduler cmd/scheduler/main.go
# sigs.k8s.io/scheduler-plugins/apis/config
apis/config/register.go:47:3: cannot use &PIDControllerArgs{} (value of type *PIDControllerArgs) as "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime".Object value in argument to scheme.AddKnownTypes: *PIDControllerArgs does not implement "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime".Object (missing method DeepCopyObject)
make: *** [Makefile:62: build-scheduler] Error 1

I troubleshoot and did not able to find the issue and use the tag as it should be. Can anyone guide the right direction for troubleshooting further. Thank You
// +k8s:deepcopy-gen:interfaces=k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime.Object
type PIDControllerArgs struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta

    // EndpointURL is the URL to which score requests will be sent.
    EndpointURL *string

    // MaxIdleConnections defines the maximum number of idle connections to the     server.
    MaxIdleConnections *int

    // IdleConnectionTimeoutSec defines the timeout for idle connections in seconds.
    IdleConnectionTimeoutSec *int

    // RequestTimeoutSec defines the timeout for requests in seconds.
    RequestTimeoutSec *int
}

/config/v1/type.go
// +k8s:deepcopy-gen:interfaces=k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime.Object
// +k8s:defaulter-gen=true
type PIDControllerArgs struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta `json:",inline"`

    // EndpointURL is the URL to which score requests will be sent.
    EndpointURL *string `json:"endpointURL,omitempty"`

    // MaxIdleConnections defines the maximum number of idle connections to the server.
    MaxIdleConnections *int `json:"maxIdleConnections,omitempty"`

    // IdleConnectionTimeoutSec defines the timeout for idle connections in seconds.
    IdleConnectionTimeoutSec *int `json:"idleConnectionTimeoutSec,omitempty"`

    // RequestTimeoutSec defines the timeout for requests in seconds.
    RequestTimeoutSec *int `json:"requestTimeoutSec,omitempty"`
}


What happens if you create doc.go files in both pkg/apis/config and pkg/apis/config/v1 with // +k8s:deepcopy-gen=package,register followed by the correct package ...? I would expect that running go generate ./... then produces generated.deepcopy.go files in both packages each containing the DeepCopy* methods required by the interface (k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime.Object)

You should have doc.go files in each package where you want to generate code:
.
└── pkg
    └── apis
        └── config
            ├── doc.go
            ├── types.go
            └── v1
                ├── doc.go
                └── types.go

The doc.go files should contain:
// +k8s:deepcopy-gen=package,register
package {name}

Where {name} is replaced with the package's name: config and v1
The structs in the 2 types.go files should include the comments that you have:
// +k8s:deepcopy-gen:interfaces=k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime.Object

Then make should work or, if you've installed deepcopy-gen:
go install k8s.io/code-generator/cmd/deepcopy-gen@latest

You can:
deepcopy-gen \
--v=9 \
./pkg/apis/config/...

This should result in generated.deepcopy.go files in both packages.
The error message (below) results because the runtime#Object interface is not satisfied without DeepCopyObject methods on your structs. The generated.deepcopy.go files satisfy this requirement.
cannot use PIDControllerArgs as "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime".Object

See the deepcopy-gen documentation.
